# Remove novalidate attribute from webform for client side validation

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I have installed [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [client side validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) extensions on my drupal project. The problem is in the webform's `form` element `novalidate` attribute is appearing, which cancels the client side validation.

[image: form html]

In webform general settings I have unchecked the disable client side validation:

[image: Webform general settings]

And finally in my form settings I have unchecked the disable client side validation:

[image: Form settings]

Cleared cache but the `novalidate` attribute is still showing. Is there any way to remove this attribute from the form?

Answer (score 2):

The [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module is automatically adding the novalidate attribute to the form.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it works (stops browser validation from getting involved) - the question is really why would you want to remove it @Janaka?

Comment: Well I suspected that it removes the client side validation plugin functionality. Because it is not working with webforms, with ajax or not.